# Passing text_field value to will_paginate as parameter in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a controller for **Books**, in index action I am using **will_paginate**. I also have filters for **title** and **authors**.

Every time **title** or **authors** changes, I am making ajax call to get updated version of `@books`.

In my index.js.erb file I have my code to render the view:

```
$('#book_list').html("<%= escape_javascript( render('show_books') ).html_safe %>");
```

My index file looks like this:

```
<%= will_paginate @books %>
<ol class="list-unstyled" id="book_list">
  <%= render 'show_books' %>
</ol>
<%= will_paginate @books %>
```

The problem is that, `will_paginate` will not be updated after AJAX call. By default I have 45 books (30 books per page, that makes 2 pages), after AJAX call I get 9 books. It is supposed to show only 1 page but it still shows 2 pages.

If I put `will_paginate` inside **book_list**, it will disappear. If I keep outside it won't be updated.

Another option is that, I can pass custom arguments to `will_paginate`, but I don't know how can I get value of a text field in a view and pass it as parameter to `will_paginate` without submitting.

These are input forms to filter books:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label :title, "Title" %><br>
  <%= text_field :book, :title, {class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Book Title" } %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label :authors, "Authors" %><br>
  <%= text_field :book, :authors, {class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Authors" } %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw your post over here [Rails3: How to pass param into custom will_paginate renderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834546/rails3-how-to-pass-param-into-custom-will-paginate-renderer) while trying to find a way to dynamically change the page links generated by will_paginate to include information from the user.

In my case the user can choose a chart to display the data shown by will_paginate, but the default page links don't pass any extra parameters so the chart they chose is not saved between pages.

My solution was to override the link to include a custom class in each of the links, which I could then have the javascript on the page target and adjust the attributes of.

Here is my override code

```
module Pageoverride
  class PaginationListLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer
    protected
      def link(text, target, attributes = {})
        if target.is_a? Fixnum
          attributes[:rel] = rel_value(target)
          target = url(target)
        end
        attributes[:href] = target
        attributes[:class] = 'chartpagetest'
        tag(:a, text, attributes)
      end
  end
end
```

The only change I made was adding a :class key to the attributes array, with the value of my custom class identifer

I include the custom renderer in my will_paginate call

```
<%= will_paginate(@dbtests, :renderer => Pageoverride::PaginationListLinkRenderer) %>
```

And my Javascript to target the elements that match my class, I am taking the current data from the variable "chart_id" ad appending it to the end of "href" attribute for each element.

```
for (index = 0; index<document.getElementsByClassName("chartpagetest").length;++index) {
                document.getElementsByClassName("chartpagetest")[index].setAttribute('href',document.getElementsByClassName("chartpagetest")[index].getAttribute('href') + "&chart="+chart_id);
            }
```

In your case you may be able to add a "hidden" attribute as well as a class to the links (attributes[:hidden] = 'false'), and set that to "true" if the page should no longer exist.